# Laravel Livewire wire:click Not Working on Chrome

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 and Livewire 2.
I've selectbox like this:

```
    <select wire:model="selectedThirdCategory" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm w-full categorySelect">
       <option>Kategori ...</option>
       @foreach($thirdCategories as $category)
       <option value="{{ $category->id }}" wire:click="firstStepSubmit">{{ $category->name }}</option>
       @endforeach
    </select>
```

With wire:click event, I'm opening next form step. This is working well on Firefox. On Chrome nothing happening. There is no error on page, no errors on console.

Only difference is responses. html response is null on Chrome.

[Response on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiWiL.jpg)

[Response on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ3fO.jpg)

Is this a Chrome issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Dont use the click event on option. Use the @change in the select tag

Comment: Glad it worked! 